# Wired mouse disconnects after a minute of usage on Windows tablet?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, tablet

I recently bought a Venue 8 pro and an OTG cable in order to plug in a wired keyboard and mouse. I have a regular Dell mouse that I used on both Linux and Windows machines with no problems. When I plug in the mouse, it works as expected for about a minute, and just disconnects automatically and says that it is having issues and to try reconnecting it. I have already restarted and switched ports and disabled power options to disable the device to save power and it still wouldn't work. I just don't know what to do now, I just bought this tablet.

Edit:
The mouse reconnects and this is what it says in the device manager:

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
A request for the USB device descriptor failed.
```

Comment: if you attach other USB devices with the cable, do they work?

Comment: @Keltari yes, my USB keyboard works perfectly fine.

Comment: remove the mouse and try uninstalling the mouse from the device manager, reboot and attach the mouse

Comment: @Keltari I've done that before even making this question. :/ Sadly it still doesn't work. I've just done Windows Update and ot still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: see if this helps.  http://pcsupport.about.com/od/errorc/a/code-43-error.htm

Comment: I eventually gave up and bought a Plixio mouse which seems to work fine.